# Django live Insert without refreshing the page

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I have this in my Homepage

[image]

everytime the customer click the `Add to cart` it will change to this , and the data will Inserted in my database

[image]

I use AJAX to prevent the page to reload/refresh

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Insert_form').submit(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var that = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'batchaddtocartHomepage' %}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: that.serialize()
                ,success: function(data){
                    console.log('Success!');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

my views.py

```
def batchaddtocartHomepage(request):

    .....
    insert = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(
        ....
    )
    insert.save()

    data = {}
    data['success'] = True
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

this is my html

```
{% for product in bought_item %}
     <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="product-image-wrapper">
               <div class="single-products">
                     <div class="productinfo text-center">
                          <img src="{{product.image.url}}" style="width:250px;height:250px;" alt="" />
                           <form method="POST"  id="Insert_form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                                <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">&#8369;&nbsp;{{product.price}}</span>
                                <h2><span >{{product.other_discount_price_formula|floatformat:'2'|intcomma}}</span></h2>
                               <div style="height: 65px;"><p>{{product.product}}</p></div>
                               <div id="qty" style="display:none;">
                               <div class="quantity buttons_added" style="width: 30%;">
                                   <input type="submit" value="-" class="minus" formaction="/updatecart_index/">
                                   <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="99" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="divshow input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="" inputmode="">
                                   <input type="submit" value="+" class="plus" formaction="/updatecart_index/">
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                         <input type="submit"  value="Add to cart" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="choose">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                                        <li><a href="{% url 'Vegetables' %}?id={{product.id}}"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>View Product 1</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {% endfor %}
```

my script

```
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("qty");
          var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
              x.style.display = "none";
          } else {
              x.style.display = "block";
          }
       }
    </script>
```

**PROBLEM** I encountered, the button only changes when I refresh the page.

this is my what i want to do in my own site https://www.landers.ph/ (please try to click the button of landers.ph site) i hope it will get you idea of what functionality i want.

**UPDATE** i remove the `script` and i add to some code in my `ajax`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Insert_form').submit(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var that = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'batchaddtocartHomepage' %}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: that.serialize()
                ,success: function(data){
                    console.log('Success!');
                    var x = document.getElementById("qty");
                    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
                    x.style.display = "block";
                    btn.style.display = "none";
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

my problem is when i click the Egg Large (1 Tray) `Add to cart` what changes is the Papaya Solo Ripe (1 pc) button

Comment: You mean `remove` button ? where is that button ? i am not seeing that button in your  code .

Comment: remove when the user click the `Add to cart` i used `input type submit`

Comment: So , you need to change that button to remove button ? But your js code is for hiding  that button? Also, please elaborate more with issue which your facing .I saw your website you said in question after refresh that `remove` button is shown .. but i am not seeing any button after refresh also only quantity div is shown below product.

Comment: if the user click the `<input type="submit"  value="Add to cart" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">` it will change to  the `quantity +/-`

Comment: i just want the functionality of https://www.landers.ph/ to my website

Comment: You just need to update your javascript so that when you receive back the 200 response from the server you update the button text. At the moment your AJAX response is just to trigger a console.log

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: i am not familiar in ajax or javascript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your hiding code inside success function of ajax.Also, use `class` selector instead of `id`.So, as you already have `that` variable which is refer to current `form` and the button and quantity div is inside form you can use `that.find(".add-to-cart").hide();` and `that.find(".qty").show();` to hide and show your elements.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Insert_form').submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);

    /*$.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'batchaddtocartHomepage' %}",
      type: 'POST',
      data: that.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {*/

    that.find(".add-to-cart").hide(); //hide button
    that.find(".qty").show(); //show qty div
    /* }
    });
    return false;
  });*/
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="product-image-wrapper">
    <div class="single-products">
      <div class="productinfo text-center">
        <img src="{{product.image.url}}" style="width:250px;height:250px;" alt="" />
        <!--use class for form-->
        <form method="POST" class="Insert_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
          <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">&#8369;&nbsp;{{product.price}}</span>
          <h2><span>{{product.other_discount_price_formula|floatformat:'2'|intcomma}}</span></h2>
          <div style="height: 65px;">
            <p>{{product.product}}</p>
          </div>
          <!--use class for qty-->
          <div class="qty" style="display:none;">
            <div class="quantity buttons_added" style="width: 30%;">
              <input type="submit" value="-" class="minus" formaction="/updatecart_index/">
              <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="99" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="divshow input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="" inputmode="">
              <input type="submit" value="+" class="plus" formaction="/updatecart_index/">
            </div>
          </div>

          <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" id="btn" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="choose">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li><a href="{% url 'Vegetables' %}?id={{product.id}}"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>View Product 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="product-image-wrapper">
    <div class="single-products">
      <div class="productinfo text-center">
        <img src="{{product.image.url}}" style="width:250px;height:250px;" alt="" />
        <form method="POST" class="Insert_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
          <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">&#8369;&nbsp;{{product.price}}</span>
          <h2><span>{{product.other_discount_price_formula|floatformat:'2'|intcomma}}</span></h2>
          <div style="height: 65px;">
            <p>{{product.product}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="qty" style="display:none;">
            <div class="quantity buttons_added" style="width: 30%;">
              <input type="submit" value="-" class="minus" formaction="/updatecart_index/">
              <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="99" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="divshow input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="" inputmode="">
              <input type="submit" value="+" class="plus" formaction="/updatecart_index/">
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" id="btn" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="choose">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li><a href="{% url 'Vegetables' %}?id={{product.id}}"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>View Product 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="product-image-wrapper">
    <div class="single-products">
      <div class="productinfo text-center">
        <img src="{{product.image.url}}" style="width:250px;height:250px;" alt="" />
        <form method="POST" class="Insert_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
          <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">&#8369;&nbsp;{{product.price}}</span>
          <h2><span>{{product.other_discount_price_formula|floatformat:'2'|intcomma}}</span></h2>
          <div style="height: 65px;">
            <p>{{product.product}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="qty" style="display:none;">
            <div class="quantity buttons_added" style="width: 30%;">
              <input type="submit" value="-" class="minus" formaction="/updatecart_index/">
              <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="99" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="divshow input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="" inputmode="">
              <input type="submit" value="+" class="plus" formaction="/updatecart_index/">
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" id="btn" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="choose">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li><a href="{% url 'Vegetables' %}?id={{product.id}}"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>View Product 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```